# Wpf Grid Layout

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, grid, grid-layout

is WPF grid layout with * width or column, heavy for UIs?

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="334" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general not. However if you have the combination of RowDefinitions with * and ColumnDefintions with *, this can lead to a performance penalty in big Grids. But this is very seldom. In fact, Grids with the length of * are one of the most used elements in WPF layouting.

Comment: My vote here. Instead of talking about the '*' or not, you should consider the Grid element as a very versatile layout manager, that comes at a cost. The row/column size manager is generally costly than a simple DockPanel or similar. Feel free to use the Grid, but favor the DockPanel wherever the layout is really simple.

Comment: Thank you Mario - i want to have simple and fast UI and my question was for that.